# Passing an icon as an argument doesn't work - google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

:) I'm trying to pass an icon as an argument to a simple marker dropping function but I can't seem to pass it properly even though I've experimented both with single and double quotes. So I have the following function and the code that uses it.

```
function addMarkerWithTimeout(position, the_image, timeout) {  //Marker dropping function
    window.setTimeout(function(the_image) {
    markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        map: map,
        draggable: false,
        icon: the_image,      //Hard-typing the url here works perfectly
        scale: 3,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP }));
    }, timeout);
}

var start_image = '../icons/favicon.ico';                      //The icon local url
addMarkerWithTimeout(routeCoordinates[0], start_image, 200);   //Calling the function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the_image from window.setTimeout

```
function addMarkerWithTimeout(position, the_image, timeout) {  //Marker 
    window.setTimeout(function() {
```